# Como remover uma div inteira no Jquery e depois adiciona-la de volta?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como posso remover uma div inteira utilizando `.empty()` ou `.remove()` e depois adicioná-la de volta em qualquer função?

Comment: As vezes nem existe a necessidade de remove-la, sendo que você irá adiciona-la novamente, usando somente o hide e show do Jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso existe o método [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/). Ele possui a mesma função do método `remove()`, exceto que ele guarda o elemento removido para ser inserido posteriormente.

**Exemplo:**

No exemplo abaixo, a `div` amarela será "excluída" da página a adicionada dentro da `div` verde ao click dos botões:

```js
var div1;
function remover(){
   div1 = $("#div1").detach();
}

function inserir(){
   $("#div2").append(div1);
}
```

```css
#div1{
   background: yellow;
   color: #000;
}
#div2{
   background: green;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
   Olá!
</div>
<div id="div2">
   Mundo!
</div>
<br>
Clique em remover:
<button onclick="remover()" type="button">Remover</button>
<br>
Depois em inserir:
<button onclick="inserir()" type="button">Inserir</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar o conteúdo com .html(), armazenar numa string qualquer, removê-la da DOM, depois recriar a DIV e preenchê-la com .html(string). Não sei quão eficiente é, mas funciona.